# How to fix a value of type future<int> can not be assigned to a variable of type int

Tags: dart, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I'm trying to insert a row to a table in database using flutter framework and when I'm assigning the returned value to a new variable I get the following error message

```
 a value of type future<int> can not be assigned to a variable of type int
```

this is the function to insert new row

```
Future<int> addContact(String contact_name, String contact_phone) async {
    Database c = await getConnection;
    Map<String, dynamic> contact = getMap(contact_name, contact_phone);
    return await c.insert("contacts", contact);
  }
```

and here where I'm getting the returned data

```
int result=db.addContact(name, phone);
```

Comment: Maybe `int result= await db.addContact(name, phone);`?

Comment: @alexkucksdorf doesn't work because awaiat need the method to be async  and you can not modify the build function of satefulWidget class

Comment: Async is contagious. You can't go back from async to sync. The caller also needs the `async` keyword and use `await` to depend on async code being completed before execution continues.

Comment: Then you should use `FutureBuilter`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please give a link for tutorial for FutureBuilder i can not get a good explanation for it

Comment: I don't know a single resource to suggest. `FutureBuilder` is used and discussed all over the place. A google search should do.

Comment: How about -  db.addContact(name, phone).then((val)
{int result = val;
print(result);
});

Answer (score 5):

addContact function has some operation which will return value when operation complete, so make a completion block here.....

```
addContact(contact_name, contact_phone).then((value) {
  //this 'value' is in int
  //This is just like a completion block
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Either use `FutureBuilder` or something like this

```
int value; //should be state variable. As we want to refresh the view after we get data

@override  
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  db.addContact(name, phone).then((value) {
       setState(() {this.value = value;});
  })
 return ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FutureBuilder`. Here is an example:

```
@override  
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder (
        future: loadFuture(), //This is the method that returns your Future
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data) {               
              return customBuild(context);  //Do stuff and build your screen from this method
            }
          } else {
            //While the future is loading, show a progressIndicator
            return new CustomProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
    );  
}
```